# How to place decoupling Capacitors in a star ground design?

Tags: grounding, decoupling-capacitor

I am in the process of routing a star-grounded amplifier pcb and wondered on how to connect the decoupling capacitors. As I see it I have two choices:

1. Connect the ground of the capacitors directly to the star-ground point.
2. Connect the ground of the capacitors "in series" between the star-ground point and the GND of the amplifier.

Basically:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIX7mC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The decoupling capacitor **must** be connected as close as possible to the supply pins of the device in order to minimize inductance in the high-frequency loop. This is true regardless of what grounding scheme is in use.

Comment: Yep... It is as close as possible to the IC... But you didn't answer my question :-)

Comment: The purpose of star grounding is to increase the inductance along the ground path. Anything that opposes this is incorrect practice.

Comment: So ... following your statements: star-ground increases inductance, decoupling capacitor should be placed with the goal of reducing inductance. So I should create a direct path between the IC GND and the capacitor GND and not run a trace back to the star ground point?

Comment: Correct. The shortest possible direct path.